# How can I change the robot's max velocity programmatically?

Tags: turtlebot, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to change the max_vel_x parameter programmatically, at runtime to increase or decrease the speed of the robot, based on environmental conditions.  Is this possible with the TrajectoryPlannerROS base local planner?

I am using the SimpleActionClient API to send goal locations to the robot.  For some of these goals, I would like to be able to also decrease the maximum speed.

Thanks in advance,
Charles

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42269/how-can-i-change-the-robot%27s-max-velocity-programmatically?/) by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 332 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) on 2012-08-24**:
After some more investigation, I learned that I can use the dynamic_reconfigure tool, and that it has a command line.  While not an elegant solution, I could execute a system command from my code, i.e. rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam set /robot_0/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS max_vel_x 0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked something similar about a C++ API for a dynamic reconfigure client [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/12276/is-there-a-c-api-for-a-dynamic-reconfigure-client/) and Pablo gave a good answer for how to get around the lack of such an API. He suggested using the service

```
/my_node/set_parameters
```

with topics

```
/my_node/parameter_descriptions-
/my_node/parameter_updates-
```

That service and those topics are provided by the dynamic reconfigure server.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use dynamic_reconfigure python API. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingDynparamToChangeHokuyoLaserParameters point 1.4

---

Originally posted by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) with karma: 408 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I make a system call to the dynamic_reconfigure server:

```
system("rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam set <node_name> \"{ param1: value1, param2: value2, ... }\"");
```

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-05-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2